# Convert HTML Code with quotation marks to string for SQL insertion

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Let's take this sample HTML:

```
    <div class="card custom-card mt-3">
        <div class="card-body" id="default">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type='text' name="project_code" placeholder="Dear Client," class="form-control" onkeyup="setvalue(this)" id="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var counterSection = 0;

    function init() {
        
        dragula([document.getElementById('default')]).on('drag', function (el) {
                el.className = el.className.replace('draggable', '');
            }).on('drop', function (el) {
                el.className += ' draggable';
            });
    </script>
```

It has both types of quotation marks and needs to be updated in a SQL table where the column type is long string.

How can I convert it to proper SQL statement since if I use single or double quotation marks , it gives errors.

My SQL statement preparation in PHP is like this:

```
'update '.$table.' set value = '.$data.' where sectionId = '.$id;
```

I want to store the above html code in $data which is supposed to be a string in order to work. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question would be improved if you were to show what server-side language and code you are using to handle the $table and $data and $id values. The correct answer is that you should either use the appropriate escape string, which is specific to the dbms you are using. The PHP docs have a section on [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) which is the preferred way, but there are also functions like [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) which can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it.

Use [parametrized prepared](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) statements like

```php
'update '.$table.' set value = ? where sectionId = ?';
```

Here every `?` is a parameter later passed to DBMS separately from query, and treated separately.

As a result, you don't need to escape anything (as you strings are not part of query anymore) and you are safe from SQL-injections.

In your case I believe it would be something like:

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("update ".$table." set value = ? where sectionId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $data, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Please notice, that table name couldn't be substituted as parameter to query, so there concatenation is still used. Although I would recommend to consider replacing it with constant name to improve readability.

Also, notice that first parameter of [`bind_param()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) takes string containing types of your parameters. Here I assumed your `$data` is string, and `$id` is integer, but you could need adjust to your data model.

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but would be more useful if it actually explains what prepared statements are. Perhaps some links to PDO documentation?

Comment: @S.Imp, on the way) Decided to post really short answer in case OP will decide to leave to use some bad escaping.

Comment: Okay, great. I think this is a much better way to that.

Comment: @markalex a correct answer is better than a short answer that just leads to more confusion. I would also discourage links to w3schools, which are full of mistakes and bad code. Try and use the official PHP docs instead.

Comment: @consolenine, added some description on how to use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1):

I found this PHP function

```
mysqli_real_escape_string()
```

It seems to do the job.